# Scraping React Elements in Ruby using Nokogiri

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to web scrape a page but part of that page is rendered using React. So it has react components. When i scrape the page, i do not see the react components and hence i cannot scrape the information in that section

e.g. in the rendered HTML i have a section like this

```
<div id="reactDiv">
  <div data-reactroot="" class="segment">
   <label> Scrape me </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But somehow when i try to find the css using Nokogiri and do this

```
html_response.css('div#reactDiv')
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x2ae63e040048 name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x2ae63e040ad4 name="id" value="reactDiv">]>]
```

It doesnt have the children elements hence i cannot scrape further.

Anyone have any other options on how to web scrape react rendered html pages?

Thanks

Comment: Do 'view source' to see if the data is in a json obnect. If it's not on the page it's coming from a XHR

Comment: can you provide the URL for the page you are trying to scrape as well as the section you are after?